# website looks weird on IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

On chrome and Safari everything looks great. this is the example URL:

http://gismanka.pl/2015/12/29/21-dni-w-japonii-czesc-i-plan-hiroszima-i-zachodnie-honsiu/

i was looking for some jquery issues, but on chrome there are no major issues. Any ideas?

Comment: share with us your ff and ie versions.

Comment: script.js is giving a error on line 85. Uncaught ReferenceError: checkSize is not defined

Comment: `On chrome and Safari everything looks great`, and then `but on chrome there are no major issues`. Whoa, that was nice...

Comment: Too many `float: right` floating right has really bad cross-browser compatability. If you remove `float: right` from the body it half fixes it on ff and ie, still has all the other `float: right`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkSize(){
                    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
                        //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });                        
                    } else { 
                        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('.widget-bar').offset().top - 150}, 'slow');  
                    }
                }
```

This function is not present and causing issues. fixing this issue might solve the problem.